# XCode 4.2 and Local git repository

Tags: git, xcode4.2

I have a project I have been adding files to regularly and noticed recently that only some of the files are being managed by the local git repository.  In other words, when I modify some of the files, there is no indication of source control status (like 'M').

The files that are exhibiting this behavior are ones created by making copies of existing files in the project outside of XCode.  For example, I would go out to finder and make a copy of a file already in the project, rename it, and go back into XCode and add the file to the project.

When I right-click on these files in XCode and choose Source Control, every menu item is grayed out.  I can't even add them to source control.

I have a feeling that copying a file already in the project caused a problem, but I have no idea how to fix it.  I have read that I can recursively remove source control from a project by issuing a bash command, but I would really rather not lose the source control history I already have.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - when I copy a file in my project in Finder, add it with XCode, a grey "?" appears where the "M" would be (Source Control notation) in the XCode project view. Does adding the effected files to your git repo manually (via terminal) work?

Comment: Not sure how to do this, but I will look up the necessary command and report back.

Comment: I used terminal to add the files to git.  Thanks.  Can I mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I right-click on these files in XCode and choose Source Control, every menu item is grayed out. I can't even add them to source control.
>
> I would really rather not lose the source control history I already have.

I couldn't reproduce this in XCode 4.2. Manually adding the files to the git repository should work - but I can't test this.

**Steps to manually add files to the git repository:**

- Open Terminal
- Navigate to the folder that your XCode project is located in.
- Run `git status`, which should tell you which files are currently untracked.
- To add *all untracked files* to git, use `git add -A` - this will add all untracked files, and remove any files which have been deleted from the git repository.
- If you'd prefer to pick which files are to be added: `git add <filename>`.
- To commit to git: `git commit`.

Once this is done, XCode should recognize that the files are being tracked and let you commit changes via the XCode source management commands.

Comment: Careful though - this will also add the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file to the repository, with very unpleasant results. You should first locate the file and then write its path into a file named .gitignore - before running the add command.